# How to perform mathematical operations on hexadecimal string in PHP

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
<?php
$hex1 = '3A7BD5';
$sum = (int) ($hex1 / 2);
echo $sum;
?>
```

Now what I am trying to do is start with hex 3A7BD5 (equiv. to dec 3832789) and half the value, to finish with something like 1D3DEB (equiv. ~1916395)

It seems as simple as trying to half the hex value but the code I have above gives the output of "1".

Comment: Take a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php ; http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php Right now your string gets silently converted to an integer(3) in the math expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `hexdec` to convert your hex string to a decimal number, and `dechex` to convert back.

```
<?php
$hex1 = hexdec('3A7BD5');
$sum = (int) ($hex1 / 2);
echo dechex($sum);
```

Result: `1d3dea`

See [This code run online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3f1624cbff55e083292fb752d06538788802591b) and [hexdec Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php) and [dechex Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php)

Using Hex Notation:

```
<?php
$hex1 = 0x3A7BD5;
$sum = (int) ($hex1 / 0x02);
echo dechex($sum);
```

Comment: Ok, I actually want a hex output but I got it with ```<?php
$hex1 = hexdec('3A7BD5');
$sum = (int) ($hex1 / 2);
$output = dechex($sum);
echo $output;
?>```

Comment: @Jimmy OK yes I missed that part of question - I have updated answer.